# How to add People in macOS Photos?

Tags: mac, photos

[Initially](https://support.apple.com/kb/PH21306?locale=en_US) there was a **+**-Button in the **People**-Album.
[image: add people]

But at some point in time this button disappeared.

I can still <kbd>CMD</kbd><kbd>I</kbd> a picture in my library and add a new person, but it for some reason does not give me the option anymore in the **People**-Album.

If I remember correctly I was able to look through a huge list of already identified faces and add a name to them.

Was this feature removed?

Comment: Yes, Photos used to suggest potential people. [I now *never* see new suggested people](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/360397/why-is-photos-not-suggesting-new-people-faces-in-the-people-album), even if I take hundreds of photos of a new friend. I don't understand why. I'm forced to manually go to a photo of that person and a name to the face via the photo.

Answer (score 1):

You can follow [this article](https://www.imore.com/how-use-people-and-places-photos-mac) on iMore to find out about how to add more people.

Although, my personal opinion is that this feature should've been more proactive and keep identifying in the background.

Comment: I cannot open the article.. What does it say ?

Comment: @ankii You sure? Just checked the link and it's working fine.

Comment: Answers on AskDifferent should be more than just a link. It's ok to include a link for reference, but please summarize the essential parts directly into your answer. This also helps in case links break in the future.