# How to delete specific "unnamed" Faces from Photos?

Tags: macos, ios, icloud, photos, photos.app

Photos for macOS, iOS, and iCloud Photos face detection often recognizes random people in crowd shots, actors in movie posters, statues, paintings in a museum, etc.

Can individual "unnamed" faces in a photo be deleted, removed, or hidden?

On macOS they are given "unnamed" face circles. The faces do not appear in the Info window's "Add Faces" section until they are named.

[image: Obi Wan and Ani on macOS]

On iOS the faces are listed in the "People" section and labeled "No Name":

[image: Obi Wan and AniOS2]

I want to delete these extraneous non-personally-known faces whenever I see them so that I can better search for and isolate known "unnamed" faces that I *do* want to name:

> [How can I show all unnamed faces in macOS Photos?](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/373635/how-can-i-show-all-unnamed-faces-in-macos-photos)